# The jumping digits to letters transformation

Tags: code-golf, string

Imagine you have an infinite sequence of the alphabet repeated infinitely many times:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcd...
```

You start at index `0`, which corresponds to the letter `a`, and the `should_write` boolean flag is `False`.

The input is a list or string of single-digit numbers. For each number `n` in the input, you should:

- Print (or add to the return value) the `n-th` item of the list if the `should_write` flag is set to `True`
- If `n` is `0`, swap the `should_write` flag.
- Otherwise move (jump) the index `n` places forward.

At the end of the input, stop (and return the result if using a function).

**Input**

A sequence of digits (list or string).

**Output**

The text that comes out after applying the above procedure.

**Examples**

```
>>> g('99010')
st
>>> g('100')
b
>>> g('2300312')
f
>>> g('390921041912042041010')
mvxyptvab
>>> g('1')
>>> g('1045')
bf
>>> g('33005780')
g
>>> g('100100102')
bcd
>>> g('012')
ab
```

Comment: Does the input have to be a string of digits, as in your test cases, or can it be a list of numbers?

Comment: Are you sure about your test cases? Several of them seem wrong to me.

Comment: @xnor a list of digits

Comment: @Caridorc In `'33005780'`, how is more than 1 char printed? The `should_write` flag starts off, is turned on for one digit and turned back off immediately, and then only turned on again at the end.

Comment: @xnor found obvious bug in my reference implementation and facepalmed, will correct testcases asap...

Comment: @PeterTaylor Taylor there was a bug in my reference implementation, testcases fixed now.

Comment: @Zgarb thanks, already fixed :)

Comment: "Print (or add to the return value) the n-th item of the list" did you mean the item currently pointed at by the index? Because you're using `n` for the current digit in the string.

Comment: With the '012' and '100100102' examples, why is the last incremented value not printed?  So for '012' I would interpret as 0 swap flag and print a, increment 1 print b, increment 2 print d.  Or is the last integer essentially ignored?

Comment: @MickyT You should really apply the operations in the order listed in the challenge: *first* you print (if the flag as set), *then* you toggle the flag (if applicable), *then* you move the index forward.

Comment: @MartinBüttner  Thanks, I just needed to adjust my thinking:)

Answer (score 4):

### Python 3, 60

```python
i=b=0
for c in input():b and print(chr(97+i%26));b^=c<1;i+=c
```

Takes a list of numbers and prints the chars on separate lines.

Basically just follows the instructions. The index is `i` and the `should_write` flag is `b`. The expression `b and` short-circuits to print only when `b` is true.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 20 bytes

Takes a string of digits as command-line argument.

```
Fda{IyOz@id?i+:dY!y}
```

This code uses a number of Pip's preinitialized variables. `i` is initially `0`, `y` is initially `""` (falsy) and `z` contains the lowercase alphabet. `a` gets the first command-line arg.

```
Fda{               }  For each digit d in a:
    IyOz@i              If y (the flag) is truthy, output letter of z at index i
                        Pip's cyclic indexing takes care of the infinite effect
          d?            If d is truthy (digit is nonzero),
            i+:d          then increment i by d;
                Y!y       otherwise, yank !y into y (thus swapping the flag)
```

An alternate way of swapping the flag would be `!:y`, with `!:` being a compute-and-assign operator just like `+:`.

```
C:\Users\dlosc> pip.py -e Fda{IyOz@id?i+:dY!y} 390921041912042041010
mvxyptvab
```

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 28 bytes

```
0q{~U{1$'a+o}&_!U^:U;+26%}/;
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=0q%7B~U%7B1%24'a%2Bo%7D%26_!U%5E%3AU%3B%2B26%25%7D%2F%3B&input=390921041912042041010)

Nothing really special here. Like xnor, I don't have a string of letters but simply a running total (mod 26) which I add to `a` when I need to print it. The `should_write` flag is kept track of in `U`.

Answer (score 2):

## R, 73 bytes

Once I got it sorted in my head:)

```r
(letters[cumsum(a<-head(scan()),-1)%%26+1])[which(cumprod(-(a<1)*2+1)<0)]
```

This takes a vector of integers from STDIN and returns a vector of letters.

Ungolfed and explanation

```r
a <- head(scan()),-1)    # get integers from stdin and drop last one
a <- cumsum(a) %% 26 + 1 # do the cumulative sum of the vector to use as a vector of letter indexes
l <- letters[a]          # vector of potential letters 
p <- -(a<1)*2+1          # turns 0's into -1 and everything else into 1
p <- cumprod(p)          # the cumlative prod then creates a vector of on and off values
f <- which(p<0)          # index values of the returned characters
l[f]                     # return vector of characters
```

Tests

```r
> (letters[cumsum(a<-head(scan(),-1))%%26+1])[which(cumprod(-(a<1)*2+1)<0)]
1: 9 9 0 1 0
6: 
Read 5 items
[1] "s" "t"
> (letters[cumsum(a<-head(scan(),-1))%%26+1])[which(cumprod(-(a<1)*2+1)<0)]
1: 1 0 0
4: 
Read 3 items
[1] "b"
> (letters[cumsum(a<-head(scan(),-1))%%26+1])[which(cumprod(-(a<1)*2+1)<0)]
1: 2 3 0 0 3 1 2
8: 
Read 7 items
[1] "f"
> (letters[cumsum(a<-head(scan(),-1))%%26+1])[which(cumprod(-(a<1)*2+1)<0)]
1: 1
2: 
Read 1 item
character(0)
> (letters[cumsum(a<-head(scan(),-1))%%26+1])[which(cumprod(-(a<1)*2+1)<0)]
1: 1 0 4 5
5: 
Read 4 items
[1] "b" "f"
> (letters[cumsum(a<-head(scan(),-1))%%26+1])[which(cumprod(-(a<1)*2+1)<0)]
1: 0 1 2
4: 
Read 3 items
[1] "a" "b"
>
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6) 76

(note: the fromCharCode function is so lengthy that for lowercase letters it's better a conversion to base 36)

Test running the snippet below in any EcmaScript 6 compliant browser

```js
g=l=>l.replace(/./g,n=>[f?(p%26+10).toString(36):'',-n?p-=-n:f=!f][0],p=f=0)

console.log=x=>O.innerHTML+=x+'\n'

;['99010','100','2300312','390921041912042041010','1','1045','33005780','100100102','012']
.forEach(t=>console.log(t+' ['+g(t)+']'))
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 59 bytes

Port of [xnor's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/60693/11261).

```ruby
->a{i=0
b=p
a.map{b&&$><<(97+i%26).chr
b=!b if _1<1
i+=_1}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3rXXtEqszbQ24kmwLuBL1chMLqpPU1FTsbGw0LM21M1WNzDT1kjOKgNKKSQqZaQrxhjaGXJnatvGGtbVQI_TcoqONdSx1DIDYSMcQSJsASUsgNgKzjaAiBiAcGwvRtWABhAYA)